# AxesSubplot not rendered after plot() in another cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I plot some data from `pandas` `DataFrame` in a `Jupyter` `notebook` cell like this:

```
    ax = data.plot('Weight', 'Height', kind='scatter', backend='matplotlib')
    print(type(ax))
    ax.plot(xs, line1, color='red')
    print(type(ax))
    ax.plot(xs, line2, color='yellow')
    print(type(ax))
```

I see that `ax` is of the type `<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`. All good.

Then, in the **next** cell, I am trying to plot another line, reusing `ax`, just like I did with `ax.plot(xs, line2, color='yellow')`:

```
ax.plot(w1_arr, errors, color='red')
print(type(ax))
```

However, nothing is rendered, except for the type of `ax`, it is the same `<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`.

Questions:

1. Why is nothing rendered? Is it because within a single Jupyter cell it is fine to 'reuse' `ax` because it reads all of the commands to plot, and then plot everything at once? But it is not fine to try to 'reuse' `ax` outside that single cell?
2. Why is the type of `ax` `AxesSubplot` and not simply `Axes`? As per [DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), it should return Axes, I have explicitly set backend='matplotlib'.

Answer (score 2):

By fiddling around I found a way to make it work, but I am researching it as well it is an interesting behaviour ad I also do not fully understand it atm.

My feeling is that it has to do with how artist and renderer are stored and persisted in the `Figure` or `Axes` classes and across jupyter cells.

The following snippet will work:

```
############################ CELL 1 ################################
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,30,10), 'b': np.random.randint(0,30,10)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot('a', 'b', kind='scatter', backend='matplotlib', ax=ax)
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10), color='red')
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10)+5, color='yellow')

############################ CELL 2 ################################
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10)+15, color='blue')
fig
```

In addition, the behaviour you observed must also be related to the inline rendering of jupyter. If you us `qt` instead by `%matplotlib qt`, which will create an external figure, the code you posted will work fine, like such:

```
############################ CELL 1 ################################
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib qt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,30,10), 'b': np.random.randint(0,30,10)})

ax = df.plot('a', 'b', kind='scatter', backend='matplotlib')
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10), color='red')
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10)+5, color='yellow')

############################ CELL 2 ################################
# minimize the figure that popped up and run the second cell
ax.plot(np.arange(0,30,10), np.arange(0,30,10)+15, color='blue')
```

If you find the rationale behind it please post it, I and maybe others would be interested.